# How to dispose Disposable in RxJava 2.0 on Android?

Tags: android, disposable

In the code below `mSafeObserver.isDisposed();` always return null pointer exception if `isDatabaseEmpty == false` (`zipped.subscribe(mSafeObserver);` is not called).

```
private SafeObserver<ResponseHelper> mSafeObserver; 

private Observer<ResponseHelper> observer = new Observer<ResponseHelper>() {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSafeObserver = new SafeObserver<>(observer);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...        
    if (isDatabaseEmpty) {
        zipped.subscribe(mSafeObserver);
    } else {
        initRecycler();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSafeObserver != null && !mSafeObserver.isDisposed()) 
        mSafeObserver.dispose();
}
```

In rxJava 1.0 this code is correct:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSubscription != null && !mSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) 
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

How to check if I can dispose Disposable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what *zipped* refers to but this how I would do it

```
private CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
private Observer<ResponseHelper> observer = 
new Observer<ResponseHelper>() {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSafeObserver = new SafeObserver<>(observer);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...        
    if (isDatabaseEmpty) {
        zipped
            .doOnSubscribe(mDisposable::add)
            .subscribe(mSafeObserver);
    } else {
        initRecycler();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDisposable.dispose();
}
```